# R: Using glmnet for a non binary response

Tags: r, glmnet

I am trying to fit a logistic ridge regression model when my observed response $y_i$ for the $i$th case is observed value of the sample of proportion of successes in $n_i$ independent Bernoulli trials. I am not being able to do this using glmnet. I get an error,
Error in lognet(x, is.sparse, ix, jx, y, weights, offset, alpha, nobs,  : 
  one multinomial or binomial class has 1 or 0 observations; not allowed

Any advise here would be helpful?

Comment: How are you telling the model $n_i$, the number of observation with a given proportion?

Comment: I am simulating data such that $y = rbinom(n=n, size=n.list, prob=pi.list)/n.list$ where pi.list comes from a logistic function.

Comment: and my $n.list = rep(30,n)$

Comment: I think you should provide counts not proportions

Comment: I think if I have proportions I should input $y$ as a 2 column matrix with yinput = cbind$(y,1)$ in glmnet(x,yinput). This works.

Comment: I have another question on this. For prediction purposes, I am familiar with naive misclassification when you want to find misclassification rates for logistic with binary outcome. If plist are the estimated probabilities  we generally say that let ynew = ifelse(plist $<0.5,0,1)$. What do you do in the binomial case or in the above case where you have proportions for response? I was thinking of doing $ynew <-  rbinom(n=length(n.listTest), size=n.listTest, prob=plist)/n.listTest$. does this make sense? I am sorry for  making this long!